# count records in web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

i want to ask how to get total count with data in web api. i have tried use `if` clause to count total record, but it only shows the total count and the data didn't show in xml format.

Are there anyway to do without `If` clause?

example from json format:

```
{
  Count: 2
   [
    {
     "userid": 1,
     "name": "emily",
     "mobile": "98724954",
     "Age": 24,
     "Date": 2020-10-04T21:05:00
     },
     "userid": 2,
     "name": "peter",
     "mobile": "42896592",
     "Age": 35,
     "Date": 2021-05-25T11:20:00
     }
    ]
```

How to make the count like the example in the xml format?

Questions: How to Count data or response and show data together with xml format in web api?

my code:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            List<TestClass> draft = new List<TestClass>();
            string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
            string sqlquery = "SELECT UserID, Name, Mobile, Age, Date From tbluser";
            sqlconn.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
            SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    draft.Add(new TestClass()
                    {
                        UserId = sdr.GetString(0),
                        Name = sdr.GetString(1),
                        Mobile = sdr.GetString(2),
                        Age = sdr.GetInt32(3),
                        Date = sdr.GetDateTime(4)
                    });
                }
            return Ok(draft);
        }
        if(test.Count>0)
        {
             return Ok(test.Count());
        }
        else
        {
             return Ok("None");
        };
```

results:

```
<int xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">10</int>
```

class:

```
public class TestClass
    {

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Mobile { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        List<TestClass> draft = new List<TestClass>();
        string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
        string sqlquery = "SELECT UserID, Name, Mobile, Age, Date From tbluser";
        sqlconn.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
        SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
        while (sdr.Read())
            {
                draft.Add(new TestClass()
                {
                    UserId = sdr.GetString(0),
                    Name = sdr.GetString(1),
                    Mobile = sdr.GetString(2),
                    Age = sdr.GetInt32(3),
                    Date = sdr.GetDateTime(4)
                });
            }
        var apiResult = new ApiResult
        {
            Count = api.Length,
            Data = api
        };
        var result= Ok(apiResult);
    }
```

Comment: The JSON snippet you've posted is not valid JSON. There are multiple syntax errors in it. Please correct it and post the actual JSON structure you're working with. Also, please post an example of the XML you are looking for.

Comment: what i want to do is to count the total record when i search in web api it show the total records on the top and it also with the data too

Comment: @Xerillio i have edited now, your answer is similar to what i want, but how to do it with sql connection, sorry for the late reply

Comment: Could you elaborate what you think is missing from my answer? It's not clear what's wrong

Comment: @Xerillio i have updated the code and the `.Length` got red line and `Data = api` *api* got red line too.

Comment: it said the Length does not contain for definition, and api cannot implicitly convert type

Comment: I've updated my answer. You simply need to change `.Length` to `.Count` since you're using a `List<TestClass>`. Also change the type of `Data` like I did in my answer.

Comment: @Xerillio put all in the test api result class?

Comment: i don't think ```var apiResult = new ApiResult
        {
            Count = api.Length,
            Data = api
        };
        var result= Ok(apiResult);``` put it in the class too, it should be in the controller

Comment: I've update the answer now with all of the changes you need in the controller action.

Comment: Thank you for the help, i know more things about coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given an example of what you expect as output, so it's a little difficult to know exactly how you want the XML to look. Also note, that your (invalid) JSON example does not match your `TestClass`, so I've assumed your `TestClass` is correct.

First, add a wrapper class so you can serialize the `Count` to XML as well:

```cs
public class TestApiResult
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public List<TestClass> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Update your controller action to put your data into an instance of this class:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ConnectionString;
    using var sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
    string sqlquery = "SELECT UserID, Name, Mobile, Age, Date From tbluser";
    sqlconn.Open();
    using var sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
    using var sdr = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();

    var data = new List<TestClass>();
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        data.Add(new TestClass()
        {
            UserId = sdr.GetString(0),
            Name = sdr.GetString(1),
            Mobile = sdr.GetString(2),
            Age = sdr.GetInt32(3),
            Date = sdr.GetDateTime(4)
        });
    }

    // The important bit:
    var apiResult = new ApiResult
    {
        Count = data.Count,
        Data = data
    };
    var result= Ok(apiResult);
}
```

This will as an example result in the following XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestApiResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Count>3</Count>
  <Data>
    <TestClass>
      <UserId>fooID</UserId>
      <Name>fooName</Name>
      <Mobile>fooMobile</Mobile>
      <Access>1</Access>
      <Date>2022-08-11T00:00:00+00:00</Date>
    </TestClass>
    <TestClass>
      <UserId>barID</UserId>
      <Name>barName</Name>
      <Mobile>barMobile</Mobile>
      <Access>2</Access>
      <Date>2022-08-12T00:00:00+00:00</Date>
    </TestClass>
    <TestClass>
      <UserId>bazID</UserId>
      <Name>bazName</Name>
      <Mobile>bazMobile</Mobile>
      <Access>3</Access>
      <Date>2022-08-13T00:00:00+00:00</Date>
    </TestClass>
  </Data>
</TestApiResult>
```

**Note**: I've added some `using` statements to your code. It's important to remember, so that application resources are properly disposed when you're not using the object anymore. See [the documentation for `using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) to get more information.

Check [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gataCS) for a test.